# how to hide dropdown menu if i click body any element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to close my DropDown menu if i click body element of outside dropdown menu .

Please give me suggestion .
My code is

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('click', '.top-nav-head>li>a',  function(){
        $(this).siblings('ul').toggle().closest('.top-nav-head>li').siblings('li').find('ul').hide();
    });

});
```

```css
.top-nav-head{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
    background:blue;
    float: left;}
.top-nav-head>li{
    
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.top-nav-head>li > a{
    color: #000;
      padding: 0 10px;
      display: block;
      line-height: 40px;
      font-size: 14px;
}
.top-nav-head>li > ul{
    position: absolute;
      display: none;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
      min-width: 140px;
      right: 0;
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: red;
    
}
.top-nav-head>li > ul>li{
    display: block;
}
.top-nav-head>li > ul>li > a{
    display: block;
          color:@white;
          padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="top-nav-head">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li class="active">
              <a href="#">Admin Module</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a ui-sref="av-kw-questions.empty">Questions</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="av-wbs">WBS Elements</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="av-lbp">Lookback planning</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Form</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Plan Component</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Project Management</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
            </ul> 
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could attach an event handler to the document that will hide your drop down menus.

You would the need to stop the event bubbling when clicking on the menu items themselves:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', function () {
        $('.top-nav-head > li > ul').hide();
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.top-nav-head>li>a', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).siblings('ul').toggle().closest('.top-nav-head>li').siblings('li').find('ul').hide();
    });

});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/j31dv2aa/)

Answer (score 0):

This will check if you have clicked on the element, just set your selector ("most" parent) and "hide" functionality:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var your_element = $('#your_element');
    if(container.has(e.target).length === 0)
    {
        //hide your element
    }
});
```